# How to automatically display relationships in logical diagram?

Tags: powerdesigner

Consider a Logical Model where Entity A and Entity B are connected via Relationship Z.

If I create a Logical Diagram (note: not another logical MODEL), I am able to drag Entity A and Entity B onto the diagram.  Since the Logical Model already "knows" that Entity A and Entity B have a relationship, I would like to be able to easily add it to my logical diagram.

I am already aware of the "Show Symbols" option whereby I can select the specific relationship that I want and have it appear. That is not a solution for me.

The problem is that I have a LARGE logical model consisting of HUNDREDS of Entities and their various relationships. I then need to create application-specific diagrams consisting of a subset of those entities.  I can easily identify and drag the 50+ entities onto a new diagram. But identifying and selecting all the associations is an exercise in frustration.

Is there an option or some sort of feature that I'm missing - or any other trick - that would allow me to add only the relationships between selected entities or all entities on a diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `Tools > Complete Links`?

Comment: That is absolutely it!  Thank you very much. I've spoken to several, long-time users of PowerDesigner - as well as to three different SAP representatives; dug through the documentation; and performed multiple Internet searches looking for this feature that I knew had to be there!  You're a lifesaver.